# Time and Space Complexity of list to str conversion in Python

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Trying to find out what is the time complexity of casting to string

```
str([1,2,6,...,3,6])
```

Pretty sure it's O(1)
Not sure how to verify.

Edit:
about space complexity, That should not be linear to list size,
thinking O(1) because string has max size.

Comment: Create some lists of difference sizes and `timeit` them. It should be linear IMO.

Comment: How could it be O(1)?  Bigger lists would obviously require more work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's linear, because bigger lists need more time and memory to convert.

[image]

Graph generated using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). Code, for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot 

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.choice(100, n).tolist(),
    kernels=[
        lambda lst: [str(x) for x in lst],
        lambda lst: list(map(str, lst)),
    ],
    labels=['[str(x) for x in lst]', 'list(map(str, lst))'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 20)],
    xlabel='N',
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=None)
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain what the couple lines of your code between `perfplot.show(` and `labels=` do? Thank you so much