# How is timeit affected by the length of a list literal?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

Update: Apparently I'm only timing the speed with which Python can read a list. This doesn't really change my question, though.

So, I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657710/time-and-space-complexity-of-list-to-str-conversion-in-python/45657775#45657775) the other day and wanted to compare what the speeds looked like. I'm new to pandas so any time I see an opportunity to do something moderately interesting, I jump on it. Anyway, I initially just tested this out with 100 numbers, thinking that would be sufficient to satisfy my itch to play with pandas. But this is what that graph looked like:

[image: list to string conversion 0-99]

Notice that there are 3 different runs. These runs were run in sequential order, but they all had a spike at the same two spots. The spots were approximately 28 and 64. So my initial thought was it had something to do with bytes, specifically 4. Maybe the first byte contains additional information about it being a list, and then the next byte is all data and every 4 bytes after that causes a spike in speed, which *kinda* made sense. So I needed to test it with more numbers. So I created a DataFrame of 3 sets of arrays, each with 1000 lists ranging in length from 0-999. I then timed them all in the same manner, that is:

```
Run 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
Run 2: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
Run 3: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

What I *expected* to see was a dramatic increase approximately every 32 items in the array, but instead there's no recurrence to the pattern(I did zoom in and look for spikes):

[image: list to string conversion 0-999]

However, you'll notice, that they all vary a lot between the numbers 400 and 682. Oddly, 1 run always a spike in the same place making the pattern harder to distinguish in the 28 and 64 points in this graph. The green line is all over the place really. Shameful.

**Question:** What's happening at the initial two spikes and why does it get "fuzzy" on the graph between 400 and 682? I just finished running a test over the 0-99 sets but this time did simple addition to each item in the array and the result was exactly linear, so I think it has something to do with strings.

I tested with other methods first, and got the same results, but the graph was messed up because I joined the results wrong, so I ran it again overnight(this took a long time) using this code to make sure the times were correctly aligned with their indexes and the runs were performed in the correct order:

```
import statistics as s
import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame([[('run_%s' % str(x + 1)), r, np.random.choice(100, r).tolist()] 
                   for r in range(0, 1000) for x in range(3)], 
                  columns=['run', 'length', 'array']).sort_values(['run', 'length'])
df['time'] = df.array.apply(lambda x: s.mean(timeit.repeat(str(x))))

# Graph
ax = df.groupby(['run', 'length']).mean().unstack('run').plot(y='time')
ax.set_ylabel('Time [ns]')
ax.set_xlabel('Array Length')
ax.legend(loc=3)
```

I also have the dataframe pickled if you'd like to see the raw data.

Comment: How did you perform these timings? Was the GC enabled or disabled?

Comment: Using Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda, how do I tell if it was enabled or not?

Comment: If you used `%timeit`, it was probably disabled. Show us how you performed the timings.

Comment: I used the `timeit` module. The code I used is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: You aren't using arrays, you are using `list`s. Also, what *exactly* do you mean by "The spots were approximately 28 and 64. So my initial thought was it had something to do with bytes, specifically 4." **What** bytes?

Comment: `timeit.repeat(str(x))` - what the heck? Were you trying to time the execution of `str` on input `x`, or were you trying to evaluate `str(x)` to a string representing Python code and then time the resulting code? This doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to replace my usage of arrays. For some reason my mind always goes to `array` when talking about lists. But they *did* come from numpy arrays. I mean 28 and 64 on the x-axis.

Comment: @user2357112 Read the original post I linked to at the top of my question. I realize it doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but that was what was asked originally.

Comment: I think you've gotten `timeit(str(x))` and `%timeit str(x)` mixed up. You're timing something completely different from what you meant to time.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It's mostly linear, which is what's expected.

Comment: Please read my post. I'm testing the increase in speed of converting lists to strings of increasing lengths.

Comment: You're *trying* to test that, but you ended up timing something entirely different.

Comment: OK, what am I testing then?

Comment: @CoryMadden OK, but again, what *exactly* do you mean by "the bytes"? What bytes?!

Comment: You are timing the *result of `str(x)`* where that is some list-literal, so you are timing the interpretation of list literals, not the conversion of `list`->`str`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know. Maybe Python arrays are limited to 4 bytes and C assigns a pointer to each item in the array. Like I said, it was just a guess.

Comment: @CoryMadden OK, see, that's what I mean. That doesn't make any sense, and it's important you understand the *distinction between lists and arrays*. They are **not the same thing** and not interchangeable. And no, python arrays are not limited to 4 bytes! You could only have an array with a single float (Ok, maybe 2 floats on old architectures)! You certainly have already used `numpy.arrays` with many, many floats.

Comment: Ok, I THINK I get it now. I'm converting them to lists and then `repeat` is reading them. That doesn't really explain why the speeds are as they are, though, does it?

Comment: OK, so my assumption to the reasoning was wrong, and what I was testing was wrong, but why is what I tested the way it is?

Comment: I edited my comment. Like I said, it's just automatic.

Comment: The `timeit` module essentially takes source code as a `str`, then runs it's own Python process, where it disables the GC and then times the code. You are passing a list-literal, the result of calling `str` on a list, *as the source code that is being timed*. You'd have to dig into the `CPython` internals, specifically, how list-literals are evaluated, to even begin to be able to speculate as to why there are these apparent "bumps". Maybe there is some optimization for short-literals, and indeed,I would expect this to run into problems with cache-size when the literals are this big.

Comment: Thank you. I very rarely use the `timeit` module and since discovering the `%timeit` module I've been using it even less, and forgot. I only started using it again because of my tests from yesterday where I realized it wasn't doing what I wanted... Anyway, hopefully someone can still answer my question. Maybe I'll add some more tags that may be relevant. This actually explains why my test that I just finished performing as I posted this that just performed simple arithmetic was linear.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does my new title make more sense?

Comment: Please be careful with your terminology. `timeit` is a module. `%timeit` is an IPython magic. What you appear to be doing is timing the minutiae of the Python interpreter's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are severely overcomplicating things using `pandas` and `.apply` here. There is no need - it is simply inefficient. Just do it the vanilla Python way:

```
In [3]: import timeit

In [4]: setup = "l = list(range({}))"

In [5]: test = "str(l)"
```

Note, `timeit` functions take a `number` parameter, which is the number of times everything is run. It defaults to `1000000`, so let's make that more reasonable, by using `number=100`, so we don't have to wait around for forever...

```
In [8]: data = [timeit.repeat(test, setup.format(n), number=100) for n in range(0, 10001, 100)]

In [9]: import statistics

In [10]: mean_data = list(map(statistics.mean, data))
```

Visual inspection of the results:

```
In [11]: mean_data
Out[11]:
[3.977467228348056e-05,
 0.0012597616684312622,
 0.002014552320664128,
 0.002637979011827459,
 0.0034494600258767605,
 0.0046060653403401375,
 0.006786816345993429,
 0.006134035007562488,
 0.006666974319765965,
 0.0073876206879504025,
 0.008359026357841989,
 0.008946725012113651,
 0.01020014965130637,
 0.0110439983351777,
 0.012085124345806738,
 0.013095536657298604,
 0.013812023680657148,
 0.014505649354153624,
 0.015109792332320163,
 0.01541508767210568,
 0.018623976677190512,
 0.018014412683745224,
 0.01837641668195526,
 0.01806374565542986,
 0.01866597666715582,
 0.021138361655175686,
 0.020885809014240902,
 0.023644315680333722,
 0.022424093661053728,
 0.024507874331902713,
 0.026360396664434422,
 0.02618172235088423,
 0.02721496132047226,
 0.026609957004742075,
 0.027632603014353663,
 0.029077719994044553,
 0.030218352350251127,
 0.03213361800105,
 0.0321545610204339,
 0.032791375007946044,
 0.033749551337677985,
 0.03418213398739075,
 0.03482868466138219,
 0.03569800598779693,
 0.035460735321976244,
 0.03980560234049335,
 0.0375820419867523,
 0.03880414469555641,
 0.03926491799453894,
 0.04079093333954612,
 0.0420664346893318,
 0.044861480011604726,
 0.045125720323994756,
 0.04562378901755437,
 0.04398221097653732,
 0.04668888701902082,
 0.04841196699999273,
 0.047662509993339576,
 0.047592316346708685,
 0.05009777001881351,
 0.04870589632385721,
 0.0532167866670837,
 0.05079756366709868,
 0.05264475334358091,
 0.05531930166762322,
 0.05283398299555605,
 0.055121281009633094,
 0.056162080339466534,
 0.05814277834724635,
 0.05694748067374652,
 0.05985202432687705,
 0.05949359833418081,
 0.05837553597909088,
 0.05975819365509475,
 0.06247356999665499,
 0.061310798317814864,
 0.06292542165222888,
 0.06698586166991542,
 0.06634997764679913,
 0.06443380867131054,
 0.06923895300133154,
 0.06685209332499653,
 0.06864909763680771,
 0.06959929631557316,
 0.06832000267847131,
 0.07180017333788176,
 0.07092387134131665,
 0.07280202202188472,
 0.07342300032420705,
 0.0745120863430202,
 0.07483605532130848,
 0.0734497313387692,
 0.0763389469939284,
 0.07811927401538317,
 0.07915793966579561,
 0.08072184936221068,
 0.08046915601395692,
 0.08565403800457716,
 0.08061318534115951,
 0.08411134833780427,
 0.0865995019945937]
```

This looks pretty darn linear to me. Now, `pandas` **is** a handy way to graph things, especially if you want a convenient wrapper around `matplotlib`'s API:

```
In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'time': mean_data, 'n':list(range(0, 10001, 100))})

In [16]: df.plot(x='n', y='time')
Out[16]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1102a4a58>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

This should get you on the right track to actually time what you've been trying to time. What you *wound up timing*, as I explained in the comments:

> You are timing the result of `str(x)` which results in some list-literal,
>   so you are timing the interpretation of list literals, not the
>   conversion of `list`->`str`

I can only speculate as to the patterns you are seeing as the result of that, but that is likely interpreter/hardware dependent. Here are my findings on my machine:

```
In [18]: data = [timeit.repeat("{}".format(str(list(range(n)))), number=100) for n in range(0, 10001, 100)]
```

[image]

And using a range that isn't so large:

```
In [23]: data = [timeit.repeat("{}".format(str(list(range(n)))), number=10000) for n in range(0, 101)]
```

And the results:
[image]

Which I guess *sort of* looks like yours. Perhaps that is better suited for it's own question, though.

Comment: I tried it without pandas first and when I joined the results to my graph it was all out of order, so I ran it again with pandas(and provided that code) just to make sure that the timings were matched up with the correct rows. Unfortunately, this was all founded on forgetting how to use `timeit` module after using iPython's `%timeit` magic. Thanks for performing the test and providing the example, though. If I had just reread the docs in the first place I could have avoided this waste of time. Though I still want to know why the length caused it to take so much longer.

Comment: @CoryMadden Again, probably depends on the interpreter and things like your processors cache-size. Also, the interpreter is probably not designed to work with list-literals that big. Perhaps you should ask a seperate question *specifically about the interpretation of list literals*. Honestly, without looking at the interpreter source code, it's going to just be like reading tea-leavs

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider another question about it then. Thanks for somewhat replicating the results on your machine, too.